# How could society collapse after alien disclosure?

Tags: aliens, post-apocalypse

How would society handle an official disclosure that we are not the top predator on earth and there is *something* hunting/preying/eating us (as per latest UFO interviews) like an alien civilization, and it is coming soon to earth?

I mean would people turn to religion? Stop working altogether, and disrupt food chains and transportation? Ending tourism as people turn inwards?
What I'm looking is reason(s) or sequence of events for the world turning post-apocaliptic waiting for aliens soon but them not coming.

---

To clarify, aliens are preying on us but are invisible on our reality. Its like we in 3d looking at a 2d world they dont know we exist and can see "from above".
So we humans have no way to stop the aliens coming here and hunting us. What I am interested really is not the actual facts on it, but how would society collapse when confronted with a revelation that it completely changes our combined perception of our place in the universe, us with each other, so disruptive of our way of thinking about ourselves that would make people stop the 9-to-5 grind and look inside themselves. Thinking such as "we are here on this earth like cattle to be consumed, why would I aspire to be a good doctor/pilot/cop/etc when there is no meaning to it?"
This would make farmers stop farming, so there would be hunger. Ships would stop going on lanes transporting goods so no more stuff in shops. Cell phones would stop being produced. Etc.
My question is how the society would collapse like this. What could be the sequence of degradation until reaching a post-apocaliptic aspect.

Hope this clarifies more.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As our [help] states, avoid asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”. This is calling for 7 billions of opinions.

Comment: Mass panic of people screaming in the streets and random fires is a movie trope. Instead, panicky people tend to go home. Folks generally adapt.

Comment: Please clarify. The beginning of the question indicates something is preying on humans, but the end of the question would indicate they are not here yet.  The progression of events would likely be different.  If we're already prey there will be some defensive actions taken, but if we're not yet prey, but might be prey soon, then the scenario could be much more lackadaisical for many.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you are looking for the most likely consequences of the discovery of aliens or are you looking to justify the collapse of society as described in the second part of your post? Societal collapse as seen on TV is extremely difficult (if not impossible) to engineer.

Answer (score 1):

**Basically facism**

People hate uncertainty, and events that result in fear and uncertainty tend to create social unrest. This unrest can manifest under different forms depending on the main factors involved, such as economical distress usually lead to unrest towards polítical/social reforms. This unrest in particular is caused by a external threat, so it is less likely that it will cause disunity, is car more likely that it will cause extreme pan-nationalism (we, humans, vs them) as well as general loyalty towards an united human front (UHF) and compliance towards it's actions.

Governments that do not give in their sovereignty to the UHF will experience the unrest directed towards themselves, as extremist groups will seem this independence as a betrayal to the human cause, in a similar fashion that many countries had fascist/communist movements and rebels in the past. To the general population, most will just blindly follow the UHF, but like most authoritarian dystopias, there will likely be freedom fighters and non compliant civilians, depending on the level of hysteria/paranoia they are dealing with the situation, they might persecute these people more harshly that they would against an actual alien invasion.

Overall, it would be similar to 1984, but with a alien threat rather them communists

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the scale.

When the predation is small, we try to take back top predator status. Compare this with how tribal groups have dealt with bears, lions, and cougars which have all preyed on humans.

When the predation is medium, we organize to fight back. Compare this with invading nomadic armies. We organized and built walls, forts, and other defensive systems.

When the predation is intense, society breaks down. Sections of land will be turned over to them. See how the Comanche nation was allowed to have a wide swath of the southern plains when we couldn't fight them. Look also at how France handled all the Viking raids - strong men took over much of society but they also allowed the Vikings to have Normandy. Religion gained power after all the fighting is done. Religion typically gains power as a multi-generational effect after conflict. So, the cathedral building in France started 100 years after the Vikings had been settled.